# Easy ways to increment with number and letters after checking DB

Tags: c#, arrays, char

Using C# and ASP.NET
Lnna is based on values that the user inputs.
I can get those values. 
Lnnai is the full form.
Last value 'i' should be incremented through 0-9,a-z and then A-Z. What would be the easiest way to look in DB for values and increment?

```
var Lnna = L + nn + a;

var ichars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();

var i = ?
```

Comment: Can you put some more details with the example data? what is `L + nn + a`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya L is a character (ie: A,B,C,D,E,F)
NN is a number (ie: 00, 01, 02... 09)
A is a char (ie: A....Z)

Comment: And what is `nn` and `a`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have edited the comment with those details

Comment: sorry, but it is still not exactly clear to me. You want to look in your database whether the value of `Lnna` exist and then increment `i` ?=! is that correct? and what do you do if it does not exist?

Comment: " *i* should be incremented through 0-9,a-z and then A-Z" if so why did you construct `ichars` with capital letters before the small ones?

Comment: I have practically messed up the whole question. Let me rephrase all that.
A-Z and then a-z.
If LNNA does not exist, then I should be 0. If exists increment LNNAI with char. @MongZhu

Comment: "What would be the easiest way to look in DB" a simple `where...like` should do it. Do you know how to query a data base table? as for the increment: make an `int counter = 0;` variable on class level, use it as an indexer in `i = ichars[counter]` and increment it after every positive match: `counter++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method I used. It works perfectly.

```
            int tl = items.ShelfId;
            var ttl = await _context.Shelfs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.ShelfId == tl);
            var l = ttl.Name;

            int tnn = items.CategoryId;
            var ttnn = await _context.Categories.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.CategoryId == tnn);
            var nn = ttnn.Subject;

            string a = items.AuthorLastName.Substring(0, 1);

            var lnna = l + nn + a;

            var ichars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();

            var currenti = _context.Items.Count(i => i.LibraryItemNumber.Contains(lnna));

            if (currenti > 0 && currenti < 62)
            {
                var i = ichars[currenti];
                var LNNAI = lnna + i;
                items.LibraryItemNumber = LNNAI;
            }
            else if (currenti == 0)
            {
                var i = ichars[0];
                var LNNAI = lnna + i;
                items.LibraryItemNumber = LNNAI;
            }
            else
            {
                items.LibraryItemNumber = "Exceed";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Examining an ASCII table yeilds
0-9 48-57
A-Z 65-90
a-z 97-122
It is much easier to increment a number than a letter so I converted the last letter to its ASCII value and incremented that then cast it back to a char and then toString.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string input = "Lnnnai";
            bool foundInDatabase = false;
            //set your value after db query
            if (foundInDatabase)
            { }//your code here
            else
            { 
                string s = input.Substring(input.Length - 1, 1);
                s = IncrementCharacter(s);
                Debug.Print(s);
                string newString  = input.Remove(input.Length - 1, 1);
                newString += s;
                Debug.Print(newString);
            }
        }
 private string IncrementCharacter(String character)
        {
            int code = Char.ConvertToUtf32(character,0);
            switch (code)
            {
                case 57:
                    return "A";
                case 90:
                    return "a";
                default:
                    code += 1;
                    return ((char)code).ToString();
            }
        }
```

to use Debug.Print import System.Diagnostics

Comment: This is an ASP.NET core project. But I think I can make it work after referring to you code. Thanks @Mary